# Using standard library to simplify pairwise iteration of container values

Tags: c++, algorithm, library

I came up with [this code](http://ideone.com/a8hcbp) whilst answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15124432/1084416).

Is there a simpler way of doing this using standard library?

I want to iterate over every object and do something with every other object.

For example, 4 values `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` would pair like:

```
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)
(2, 3), (2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

Each value combines with every other value. None combine with themselves, and symmetric pairings are considered the same.

This might be useful in a collision system where you want to check every solid with every other.

```
template<typename Iter, typename Func>
void pair_wise(Iter it, Iter last, Func func) {
    while(it != last) {
        Iter other = it;
        ++other;
        while(other != last) {
            func(*it, *other);
            ++other;
        }
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> values = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    pair_wise(values.begin(), values.end(),
              [](int& lhs, int& rhs) {
                  std::cout << "(" << lhs << ", " << rhs << ")\n";
              });                  
}
```

Output:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
template<typename Iter, typename Func>
void combine_pairwise(Iter first, Iter last, Func func)
{
   for(; first != last; ++first)
      std::for_each(std::next(first), last, std::bind(func, *first, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

but if I was doing this in real code I would opt not to. The above is basically just being complicated for the hell of it. I would write the following in *real* code:

```
template<typename Iter, typename Func>
void combine_pairwise(Iter first, Iter last, Func func)
{
    for(; first != last; ++first)
        for(Iter next = std::next(first); next != last; ++next)
            func(*first, *next);
}
```

Comment: I think the two `for` loops are clearer than my two `while` loops. Having the `next` makes it clearer that the inner loop is over an [increasingly smaller](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68406) sub-list.

Comment: @PeterWood I don't know why, but even seasoned C++ devs love to write `iter i = begin; while(i != end){ /*...*/ ++i; }` (or the equivalent) instead of using a for loop. I find it constantly in other people's code; And it's *much* harder to quickly understand what's going on (it's longer too).

Comment: Normally I would write a `for` loop, but as the iterators were passed in and no initialisation was necessary I just jumped straight to the condition: `while`. It doesn't feel quite right to have empty initialisation in the `for`, but having thought about it I prefer it to `while`, now.

Answer (score 5):

It would be possible to write as `for_each` call to a functor writing `for_each` again, but I don't think it would actually be shorter.

I don't think `pair_wise` is a good name. There are two many things that it could mean. I'd suggest something with `combinations` as it calls the function for all 2-combinations.

Comment: Maybe `pairwise_combinations`.

Comment: Or `combine_pairwise`

Comment: @PeterWood: Yes, those are decent names.